Importing "Common Data Format" (CDF) into R
I have to import some special "common data format" (CDF) by the MMS Science Data Centre.
As I know cdf files can be imported into R using netcdf associated packages. However, I have downloaded multiple data from the site and import into R with no success. Whenever I import it into R, error occurs, commonly as:

( package: RNetCDF) Error in nc_open("XXX.cdf") :
Error in nc_open trying to open file XXX.cdf (return_on_error= FALSE )

(ncdf4) Error in read.nc("XXX.cdf", : inherits(ncfile, "NetCDF") is not TRUE


I have exhausted my options and yet the only way is to send it into MatLab (where my collaborator usually does).
May I know if there is any option to successfully import the data into my environment? I have attached one of the files for your kind reference.
https://github.com/takheru/MMS1_FGMS_CDF/tree/96848009eabc516fea02b8e8558f6cde831f416d
I wish to know how to import this dataset into R, as RNetCDF and cdf4 did not work.

For RNetCDF & ncdf4 you'd need a NetCDF file (.nc), what you probably have is a different format described here - https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/ . Try to convert it first ( https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/html/dttools.html ) . Or perhaps use Python libraries ( https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/html/user_supplied_sw.html ) through reticulate. Note that the link included seems to point to a private repository, only accessible for you & your team.
